# Problems with acc/gyro sample rate in different iPhone models

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, sensors, core-motion

As described in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_processed_device-motion_data), I am processing a steady stream of motion updates, namely 60 readings/second from the accelerometer and gyroscope sensors.

However, for the same movement recording, I get `98` readings on average on an iPhone 6 and SE2 but `205` on average on the latest versions (12 & 13). This is a significant difference. The movement's pattern remains similar apart from some value changes in intensity. But I am not sure why the older versions have much fewer readings than the newer ones.

Any ideas why this is the case and if something can be done to improve it?

Edit:

It seems that the older versions are not actually sampling `60Hz`. For some reason, some data is being thrown away. Currently, the real sampling rate appears to be ~40Hz in one of the old devices. The new versions are the ones that are indeed sampling 60 readings per second.

In this forum [here](https://mbientlab.com/community/discussion/1608/problems-with-acc-gyro-sample-rate-in-ios), for example, people suggested that it is a firmware problem. This makes sense for iPhone 6. Though iPhone SE2 came out on 2020. Seems odd that they didn't fix it.

Comment: Out of interest: why is this relevant to your use case? Both values seem sufficiently high?

Comment: I am collecting a dataset for ML models and would like to have consistency in the data from the devices. Although initial tests show that it does not affect the performance so much.

Comment: Then maybe just clip your update rate at the lower value?

Comment: Yes, I will probably do that since this seems to be a firmware/hardware issue with older iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a deep underlying problem with the devices themselves. Nothing much can be done for it.